# GitLab Change LDAP bind username structure

Tags: ruby, ldap, gitlab, windows-server-2012

I would like to change how Gitlab verifies authentication with the AD, Since it sends the request as "CN=user ou=xx dc=xx". But the AD needs it to be sent as Domain\user. How can I change Gitlab config to send "domain\username' in bind request ?

Or why would the Windows AD reject the authentication?

Below is my LDAP configuration

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = {
'main' => {
  'label' => 'AD',
  'host' =>  '10.0.0.1',
  'port' => 389,
  'uid' => 'sAMAccountName',
  'base' => 'DC=AAA,DC=ORG,DC=LOCAL',
 'bind_dn' => 'AAA\abcdefgh',
 'password' => 'Password4',
  'block_auto_created_users'=> 'true',
  'active_directory' => true,
  'lowercase_usernames' => true,

        }
}
```

The wireshark image is below.

[image: Wireshark Ldap authentication request]

Bind Password sent packet 4.
[image: Bind Password sent packet 4]

Bind Password sent packet 18
[image: Bind Password sent packet 18]

Comment: Oops, Need to know how to change gitlab so that it sends 'domain\username' in bind request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Directory doesn't *need* the logon to be in the format domain\uid -- that's one of the three valid ID formats you can use when binding to AD via LDAP, but uid@domain and LDAP fully qualified DN are equally valid. What GitLab does is binds to AD using the bind_dn and password in the config (wireshark #4), searches at the base configured as 'base' for `(&(sAMAccountName=*user supplied uid*))` (wireshark #11), returns the fully qualified DN of the identified account (wireshark #16), and then validates the user's credentials by binding with the fully qualified DN and user-supplied password (wireshark #18).

52e (in the bind error data) is returned when the user ID matches a valid user but the password is incorrect. Is the correct user being found for the ID supplied (i.e. the user *is* in the dc=aaa,dc=org,dc=local domain, and can be found under Head Office\Users OU)? If you select packet 18, you'll see the password within the packet data -- verify something didn't get mangled in transit or mistyped.

Comment: Thank you for your response, both the passwords are the same, I have added the password response to the question!

Comment: Is the correct user being found for the ID supplied ?: yes the user does exist in the Head Office\Users OU.